# How to change time output With Angular Datepipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have integrated a date picker for display data for the line chart. I got error with date format. It shows in India Standard Time (IST) instead of GMT. Here's the result I got.

**Request URL Headers**
http://172.16.1.231:8009/api/HeatBalance/0/Wed%20Dec%2015%202021%2000:00:00%20GMT+0800%20(Singapore%20Standard%20Time)/Sun%20Dec%2019%202021%2000:00:00%20GMT+0800%20(Singapore%20Standard%20Time)

**Component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-md-6">
      <label>From Date : </label>

      <md-input-container class="marginleft15">
        <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="frompicker" [(ngModel)]="fromdate" readonly>
        <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="frompicker"></button>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-datepicker #frompicker></md-datepicker>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-md-6">
      <label>To Date : </label>

      <md-input-container class="marginleft15">
        <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="topicker" [(ngModel)]="todate" readonly>
        <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="topicker"></button>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-datepicker #topicker></md-datepicker>

    </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
fromDateChanged(newDate: any) {
    this.fromdate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(newDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.todate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.todate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if (this.isGraphTab) {
      this.loadChart(this.fromdate, this.todate);
    }
    this.getHeatReportData(this.fromdate, this.todate);
  }

  toDateChanged(newDate: any) {
    this.fromdate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.fromdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.todate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(newDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if (this.isGraphTab) {
      this.loadChart(this.fromdate, this.todate);
    }
    this.getHeatReportData(this.fromdate, this.todate);
  }
```

I need a solution to fix this issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the timezone using Angular DatePipe.

Use:
let gmtdate = new Date(localDate).toUTCString()